# subtract value from order with ajax commerce pane

Tags: ajax, commerce

I create commerce pane according to [this tutorial](http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/custom-commerce-checkout-panes) , I want to subtract amount of order by commerce pane with Ajax.

[image]

Suppose if user click subtract amount button , I want the text field value subtract from order and then order should be updated automatically, something like commerce coupon do,
I try to find out how coupon works, but not get result.
any body know how can I achieve this job?

**update**
I try below code but not work :(
my big problem is subtracting amount from order after ajax submit .

```
/*
 * Checkout pane callback: credit checkout form
 */
function rah_cc_pane_checkout_form($form, &$form_state, $checkout_pane, $order) {
  // Allow to replace pane content with ajax calls.

  $pane_form = array(
    '#prefix' => '<div id="commerce-checkout-credit-ajax-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>', 
  );

  // Store the payment methods in the form for validation purposes.
  $pane_form['credit_code'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('credit Code'),
    '#description' => t('Enter here your credit code.'),
  );
  $pane_form['amount'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',

    '#title' => t('amount'),
    '#default_value' =>200,
  );

  if (variable_get('rah_cc_checkout_enable_add_button', TRUE)) {
    $pane_form['credit_add'] = array(
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => t('subtract amount'),
      '#name' => 'subtract_amount',
      '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => 'rah_cc_subtract_amount_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'commerce-checkout-credit-ajax-wrapper',
      ),
    );
  }

  if (isset($form_state['triggering_element']) && $form_state['triggering_element']['#name'] == 'subtract_amount') {
    //  form_set_error('',$form_state);

    $amount = $form_state['input']['credit']['amount'];
    //var_dump($form_state['input']['credit']['credit_code']);

    if (!empty($amount)) {  
      if (rah_cc_redeem_code($amount, $order)) {
        // Clear the field value so that the credit code does not get
        // resubmitted causing an error when user uses main "Continue to next
        // step" submit.
        $pane_form['aomunt']['#value'] = '';

        // Reload the order so it is not out of date.
        $order = commerce_order_load($order->order_id);

        // Recalculate discounts.
        commerce_cart_order_refresh($order);
      }
    }
    else {
      drupal_set_message(t('Please enter a code.'), 'error');
    }
  }

  // Extract the View and display keys from the cart contents pane setting.
  $pane_view = variable_get('rah_cc_checkout_pane_view', 'order_credit_list|checkout');
  if ($pane_view != 'none') {
    list($view_id, $display_id) = explode('|', $pane_view);
    if (!empty($view_id) && !empty($display_id) && views_get_view($view_id)) {
      $pane_form['redeemed_credits'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => commerce_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, array($order->order_id)),
      );
    }
  }

  // Display any new status messages added by this pane within the pane's area.
  if (drupal_get_messages(NULL, FALSE)) {
    $pane_form['status_messages'] = array(
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => theme('status_messages'),
      '#weight' => -1,
    );
  }
//  ym($form);
  return $pane_form;
}

 * Ajax callback: credit add button.
 */
function rah_cc_subtract_amount_callback($form, &$form_state) {
  // Re-render the cart summary.
  list($view_id, $display_id) = explode('|', variable_get('commerce_cart_contents_pane_view', 'commerce_cart_summary|default'));
  $cart_summary = commerce_embed_view($view_id, $display_id, array($form_state['order']->order_id));
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('.view-commerce-cart-summary', $cart_summary);

  // Re-render credit pane
  $credit_pane = $form['credit'];
  $commands[] = ajax_command_replace('#commerce-checkout-credit-ajax-wrapper', drupal_render($credit_pane));

  // Allow other modules to alter the commands
  drupal_alter('rah_cc_add_credit_ajax', $commands, $form, $form_state);

  return array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
}


function rah_cc_redeem_code($amount, $order) {
  // Trim trailing spaces.
  $amount = trim($amount);
  //$coupon = commerce_coupon_load_by_code($code);

  if ($amount) {
    $order_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('commerce_order', $order);



        // Allow modules to alter whether the coupon is redeemable.
          //rules_invoke_all('commerce_coupon_redeem', $coupon_wrapper, $order_wrapper);

        rah_cc_fixed_amount($order_wrapper,$amount);
  }
}

function rah_cc_fixed_amount(EntityDrupalWrapper $wrapper, $amount) {
  $discount_price =array('amount' => -$amount,'currency_code'=>'IRR','data'=>array('components'=>''));
  $discount_name=t('gift card');
  switch ($wrapper->type()) {
    case 'commerce_order':
      // Set reference to the discount.
      // @todo: It doesn't work with the wrapper.
      $order = $wrapper->value();
      $delta = $wrapper->commerce_discounts->count();
      commerce_discount_add_line_item($wrapper, $discount_name, $discount_price);

      // Updating the commerce order calculate price; For some reason, without
      // the following call to commerce_order_calculate_total() the discount
      // components aren't re-added after they get deleted in
      // commerce_discount_commerce_order_presave().
      commerce_order_calculate_total($order);
      break;

    case 'commerce_line_item':
      // Check whether this discount was already added as a price component.
      $price_data = $wrapper->commerce_unit_price->data->value();

      foreach ($price_data['components'] as $component) {
        if (!empty($component['price']['data']['discount_name']) && $component['price']['data']['discount_name'] == $discount_wrapper->getIdentifier()) {
          return;
        }
      }

      commerce_discount_add_price_component($wrapper, $discount_name, $discount_price);
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: With regard to the meta question you posted, I wanted to take a look at this one. While I don't immediately know the answer, and certainly haven't deliberately ignored the question because who it the author, had it not been because of the meta question, I would have stopped reading at the first sentence. Referring to external sources of info causes me to find another question; it means the OP expects me to gather more information myself, and to me it's just not worth it, bounty or not. I'd read http://sscce.org/ and update the question accordingly to increase chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: On a related note, I stumbled on this article just now: http://www.takipioncode.com/2014/02/03/the-anatomy-of-a-great-stack-overflow-question-after-analyzing-10000/